# Uploading multiple files with metadata in SharePoint 2013

Tags: document-library, managed-metadata, 2013, metadata, file

Is it possible to upload multiple files with metadata in the document library in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is still not supported to upload multiple files with managed metadata or simple metadata.